# scrapy spider pass parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have a spider like this

```
def __init__(self, FirstDateString, LastDateString):
```

and I called if from my CMD like this:

```
scrapy crawl Test -a FirstDateString=1st February 2014 -a LastDateString=31th January 2014
```

but I get this exception:

```
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

crawl: error: running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supp
orted
```

Help please

Comment: why downvoting please? i have a problem, i tried to solve it. i make as the official documetation says, so what wrong i did?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think it has something to do with the double -a argument you're giving

Comment: @Synthetica i read that i have to make a new `-a` for each parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use quotes around your argument values:

```
scrapy crawl Test -a FirstDateString="1st February 2014" -a LastDateString="31th January 2014"
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend, Also thanks for your ansewr yesterday, i didn't have the time to ready it yet but i will today. i appreciate you help as alwasy